# Facebook Like button warning, but prevents sharing

Tags: facebook, error, facebook-graph

I [added a FB Like button](http://www.superlogical.net) to my Wordpress template, and when I click Like, I receive an error, which pops up and says:

There was an error liking the page. If you are the page owner, please try running your page through the linter on the Facebook devsite (https://developers.facebook.com/tools/lint/) and fixing any errors.

The Lint Checker (now) gives no Error or Warnings, after I removed a duplicate og:description tag.

Why is it not working?

Answer (score 1):

The AddThis forum has [several threads](http://www.addthis.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=5&t=33079&sid=4713ecd6d95295376b2ca113d3bc8422) (example) over the last couple days reporting problems with the Like button, and an employee has confirmed something's going on at Facebook's end. He doesn't provide any detail, unfortunately, just the same boilerplate message in all the threads.

My own client sites, one of which is also using AddThis for the like button, don't seem to be affected, so you might give it a day or two to see if the problem resolves.

**EDIT**
I just noticed that the linter does seem to be [recording](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/lint/?url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.superlogical.net%2Fspecial-interest%2Ffun%2Ffunny%2F2011%2F07%2Ffunny-star-wars-facebook-status-updates%2F) one like action for the most recent post at the moment, and thirteen for the next down. So they're apparently sneaking through at least sometimes.